# Rename Files After Pulling up same name file from different servers

Tags: shell-script, scp, file-copy

There is a file named "dhcp.db" on all my DHCP servers.

I need to fetch this file from all the dhcp servers and place them in a folder of my Enterprise server.
However I'm not able to do so as the file got replaced with the same file (Due to same name) from another server.

```
scp ${DHCPSRV}:/opt/qip/dhcp/dhcp.db /tmp/dhcpdb/ > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

simply rename file when it is copied

```
 scp ${DHCPSRV}:/opt/qip/dhcp/dhcp.db /tmp/dhcpdb/dhcp-${DHCPSRV}.db
```

- I assume you have some loop which give value to `${DHCPSRV}`
- I don't see the need of `> /dev/null`